# Can't make div look the same in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.
In IE there is no padding for some divs. I tried different solutions, but nothing helped.

Here is screenshot:

chrome screen:
  [image]

IE screen: 
     [image]

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o9lugznzr399vfr/I3x_oWFgvo - files on dropbox.

Comment: did u try aligning the 2 divs containing text and video using float attribute ?

Comment: Do you mean add float:right and float: left ?

Comment: WC :) just checkout my tutorial on aligning 3 Divs side by side using float values if u get time..It will surely be helpful in future :)  http://codejigz.com/forget-tables-use-divscss-for-page-layouts/

Comment: oh, I remembered. I have another site with bootstrap and I have porblem with border, that looks dotted in IE and my navbar is wrapping in this stupid explorer. Do you have time to look at it ?

Comment: or I will create new question for it.

Comment: do create a new Question..also what version of IE are u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at @MattWilson answer on this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105551/1416911

Answer (score 0):

This will solve all your problems:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```